# Echarts pie with dataset

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want draw a pie like [this](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsDOBTAThLGAXLANprrLkWzQCGAtlsQOQCCAxuwRrAGI7B6zADRUKYAJ4gmsZiHwix6ACa0wtYmWrUksAG60ANgFcZADgCswmgxnNazWAF9R2iroMmZAdgCc1ukYWACNHJyVYAF0xcPRopwBuIA), and I want to store data in `dataset`:

```js
option = {
  dataset: {
    dimensions: ['a', 'b'],
    source: { a: 85, b: 79 }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'template',
      type: 'pie',
      // get data from dataset
    }
  ]
};
```

`source` is an object, so I can just reset the dataset when `source` was changed and dont need to do like`option.series[0].data[0].value = ...` for every value.

I was try to set `encode.value = ['a', 'b']` or some other settings but it was not work. How can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

The source format of your dataset should be one of these 3 formats :

```js
source: [
  {name: 'a', value: 85},
  {name: 'b', value: 79},
]
```

```js
source: [
  ['name', 'value'],
  ['a', 85],
  ['b',79]
]
```

```js
source: {
  'name': ['a', 'b'],
  'value': [85, 79],
}
```

For example :

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

option = {
  dataset: {
    source: [
      {name: 'a', value: 85},
      {name: 'b', value: 79},
    ]
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'template',
      type: 'pie',
    }
  ]
};

myChart .setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.3.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is great. But for some reason I can not change the format for `source` (or just can take it in an array like `[{ a: 85, b: 79 }]`). So I want to change the series setting to achive it. Have any other solutions?