# How to plot multiple pie charts with Apache ECharts using dataset and source

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a dataset like this:

Headers Array:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

Data Array:

```
[[5, 15, 25],
[10, 20, 30]]
```

I want my chart to look like the chart below, but I prefer not to pre-process the data. Is it possible to user `dataset` and `source` and avoid pre-processing? There is a related Q/A in the [site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72168626/3495601) but I wasn't able to get it working in this particular case.

```js
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '100',
      right: "300",
      data: [["a", 5], ["b", 5], ["c",5]],
      encode: {value: 1},
      label: {formatter: "{@[0]}: {d}%"}
    },
   {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '100',
      left: "300",
      data: [["a", 10], ["b", 20], ["c", 30]],
      encode: {value: 1},
      label: {formatter: "{@[0]}: {d}%"}
    },
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is closest I could get with `dataset` and `source` options. I wasn't able to display headers.

```js
option = {
  dataset: {
    dimensions: ["a", "b", "c"],
    source: [[5, 15, 25], [10, 20, 30]]
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '100',
      right: "300",
      seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
      encode: {value: 0},
      label: {formatter: "{@[0]}: {d}%"}
    },
   {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '100',
      left: "300",
      encode: {value: 1},
      seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
      label: {formatter: "{@[1]}: {d}%"}
    },
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nested loop (map) not a solution?

Comment: @cmgchess I can pre-process the data and transform it to a form that I know how to plot. I am interested to know if there is a way to use the data in its current from?

Comment: i see you have solved it. correct?

Comment: @cmgchess, I wasn't able to solve it completely, I don't know how to display the headers in the second example,  `a`, `b`, `c`.

Comment: found a way to customise label. not sure if there is a better way tho. havent used echarts before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue you seem to have is with the labels. How about a custom formatting function for the label

```js
const headers =  ["a", "b", "c"]
const dataset = [[5, 15, 25], [10, 20, 30]]

const customLabel = (params) =>  `${headers[params.dataIndex]}: ${params.percent}%`;


const option = {
  dataset: {
    dimensions: headers,
    source: dataset
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '100',
      right: "300",
      seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
      encode: { value: 0 },
      label: {
        formatter: customLabel, 
        emphasis: {
          formatter: customLabel
        }
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '100',
      left: "300",
      encode: { value: 1 },
      seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
      label: {
        formatter: customLabel, 
        emphasis: {
          formatter: customLabel
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};


let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <div id="main" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```